# Empty EditText Android Crash

Tags: android, android-edittext

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            AtimesB = nrB * nrA;
            try {
                AtimesB = Integer.parseInt(editA.getText().toString());
            }catch(NumberFormatException e){
                textInC.setText("Error!");
                usableInt = false;
                }
            if(AtimesB == Integer.parseInt(editA.getText().toString())){
                editA.setText("");
                textC.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#87d9ff"));
                textC.append("CORECCT: " + nrB + " x " + nrA + " = " + AtimesB + "\n");
                textInC.setText("");
                nrA = rand.nextInt(50)+1;
                nrB = rand.nextInt(50)+1;
                textA.setText(String.valueOf(nrA));
                textB.setText(String.valueOf(nrB));
            }else if(usableInt = false){
                           textInC.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                           textInC.setText("Error");

            }else{
                textInC.setText("INCORECCT");
            }
        }
```

Any idea how to fix this? When I click on the button with empty EditText, the application crashes.

Thanks.

Comment: Fix "what"? Was it the crash? Can you send the log? Btw, you have an assignment instead of a comparison, `usableInt = false` is missing a `=`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your integer parsing is both inefficient and broken. You're doing the same thing twice. Whenever you write the exact same code twice, you should ask yourself if you're doing it wrong.

Try this:

```
try {
     if(AtimesB == Integer.parseInt(editA.getText().toString())) {
         editA.setText("");
         textC.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#87d9ff"));
         textC.append("CORECCT: " + nrB + " x " + nrA + " = " + AtimesB + "\n");
         [...]
     }
} catch(NumberFormatException e){
     textInC.setText("Error!");
     usableInt = false;
}
```

Also, like I mentioned in a comment, you're missing a `=` in the comparison (`if(usableInt = false`).

Comment: Thanks for the example, it worked like a newly baked muffins.

Comment: Great, now you made me hungry :P Good luck with your app!

Answer (score 1):

You have one try/catch surrounding a direct call to parseInt on the EditText's text value, but then later on you do it again.  This is probably where you're throwing an exception.

Comment: Thanks for putting sense into it, really appreciate it. Somone on another forum told me to do this :/. Glad to get it fixed.